# Why use abi encoding/decoding for method parameters? Why not simply separate the parameters in the method signature?

Tags: solidity, abi, encoding, decoding

I have seen source codes where they would encode a bunch of parameters into a single `bytes` parameter and pass it into a function, what's the real purpose of doing it? For example:

```
function hello(bytes memory data) public {
  (string memory name, uint256 age) = abi.decode(data, (string, uint));
  // do something with name and age
}
```

In the example above, both `name` and `age` can be passed into `hello()` function as a single parameter `data`. But within the function, I will still have to know how to decode `data`, which means that I already know beforehand what will be passed into this function. Then, why even use encode/decode and not just like this:

```
function hello(string name, uint256 age) public {
  // do something with name and age
}
```

Isn't it more straightforward to simply separate the parameters in the method arguments than having to decode it later? In fact, as a client interacting with this contract, I don't have to go through the trouble of encoding the parameters; I can just easily pass the values into the method!

What's the benefits of using abi encoding/decoding compared to just separating the arguments? In what scenario should I consider using the abi encoding/decoding method over separate the arguments in a function? What should be the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it just comes down to what the purpose of the function is.  If you want a function that allows you to run arbitrary functions on behalf of that contract (e.g. a multisig), you don't want to limit the type of inputs/functions you can run, so you just make a general one

Comment: How can it be a general one because the contract receiving the `data` bytes will still need to decode it? During decoding, the contract already knows the parameters to decode from the bytes. Meaning, even if I pass in addition values in the `data` bytes, they won’t be decoded because the receiving contract function doesn’t know beforehand.

Comment: Here's an example, check out the submitTransaction function: https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol